# Refresh ListView after I send new data to the server

Tags: android, android-listview

I have an Activity that displays a `ListView`. I use an `AsyncTask` to get data from a server and populate them to the list.

When I'm clicking on actionbar, a new Activity starts ( styled like a Dialog ) - user adds some data clicks "send" and I send them to the server. Then this Dialog-Activity closes and I return to the previous one when I want to refresh the list and add the new data.

Tried to run the AsyncTask on the `onResume()` method but while I get the new data  along with the previous I get them all twice cause AsyncTask runs on the onCreate() too.

1) Even the first time the Activity goes through `onStart, onCreate and onResume` so I have the list data displayed twice. 
Should I use something like a flag so the first time the Activity starts shouldn't run that code?

2) I can't think how `notifyDataSetChanged` can help me since I populate the data from a server. I have a custom Adapter extending `ArrayAdapter`.

**Code**

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);


    JSONSpotTask task = new JSONSpotTask();     //task
    task.execute();
    try {
        task.get();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    list1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview1);
    ta = new TipsAdapter(this, R.layout.row_list_item, results);
    list1.setAdapter(ta);


}   



@Override
protected void onResume() {                     
    super.onResume();                               

    JSONSpotTask task = new JSONSpotTask();     //task
    task.execute();
    try {
        task.get();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    list1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview1);
    ta = new TipsAdapter(this, R.layout.row_list_item, results);
    list1.setAdapter(ta);
}
```

Thank you

Comment: your problem is familiar I think. Your full source code will be helpful!

Comment: If I run the AsyncTask **only** on the onResume() there is no problem but is it ok to move the AsyncTask  code  run on the `onResume()` and nothing on the `onCreate()`  ?

Comment: Yes - see my answer - that is probably the better way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that the creation loop will always do `onResume` after `onCreate`, you should only display the list data in `onResume()`. Then it will only be done once on the inital run and will also be done whenever the Activity comes to the foreground.

If you know that even when it comes to the foreground it wont always need redoing, I would use  a flag which is set in `onCreate` and by the "dialog" `Activity`. But you mind find it safer to always redisplay on every `onResume`.

Comment: I'll leave it that way for the time being because it seems as the only way it can work

Answer (score 0):

You should use notifdatasetchanges only if you have updated results array. Otherwise you should create new adapter with result array in onPostExecute callback and bind it to listview